# How to use template variables in alert filter field of Alert list panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to repeat the rows for a multi-value template variable which represents different services within the same environment. Dashboard is divided into row - one per each value of the multi-value variable - and I put different graphs with an Alert List panel. No problem with graphs as defined [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/) , I can repeat them (actually one row per variable value). However, whenever I use template variable ($deployment_name as shown in the screenshot below) for alert filtering, I see nothing.

[image]

I wonder if variables are not being supported in the alert filter box or I am doing something wrong here? Because, hardcoding the value I would like to filter works seems to be work and whenever I create the Alert List in a separate row in order to use the Repeat option defined in itself it can fetch all the alerts from the folder. I am just trying to keep the Alert List per row (component) in order to make them easier to read/check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:
`~ /^$deployment_name$/` or `$var-deployment_name`?